# Rules engine for partial data

Tags: rules, rule-engine, business-rules

Do you know a rule engine (preferable for JVM), which knows to handle partial data?

I.e. while some of objects properties are unknown, the rule engine will try understand whether a rule is applicable based on known properties. And so the answer for "is condition satisfied?" will be true or false or "don't know"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rulette](https://github.com/kislayverma/Rulette) to determine ALL applicable rules.

If the input does not cover the entire rule input set, it is assumed that "Any" value for these properties will suffice and the entire set of matching rules is returned. How to further interpret this data is left to the caller.